# paperclip - dynamic use of :path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm using paperclip to attach file.

In my case, I want to save attached file for each of document.

So, my paperclip model class looks like

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'attachments'
  self.primary_key = 'srl'

  @@document_srl

  validates :document_srl,
            :presence => true,
            :numericality => { only_integer: true },
            allow_nil: false

  has_attached_file :attached,
                    :path => :save_path
  validates_attachment_content_type :attached, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  def save_path
    ":attachment/#{@@document_srl}/:id/:style/:filename"
  end
end
```

for **has_attached_file**, I want to generate path **dynamically** related for document_srl.
(I will set value of document_srl when I create this model's instance)
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use Paperclip.interpolates for this work.

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'attachments'
  self.primary_key = 'srl'

  validates :document_srl,
            :presence => true,
            :numericality => { only_integer: true },
            allow_nil: false

  has_attached_file :attached,
                    :path => ":attachment/:document_srl/:id/:style/:filename"
  validates_attachment_content_type :attached, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  Paperclip.interpolates :document_srl do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.document_srl
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried to use it but not getting it done, I have a controller and a model. Can you please explain how can I make path dynamic ? I tried to pass folder path from controller as param.

Comment: More information on this link https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations